# Creating a random n x n matrix with each row and column adding to 1

Tags: python, matrix

I want to create a random n x n matrix with decimal numbers as elements.  Each element has to be greater than zero and each row/column should add up to one.  The elements should otherwise be random except for the two restrictions described above.

So far, I have a lot of nested for loops using `random.random()` but the code is really messy. Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Also please refrain from the name-calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy if the elements are all allowed to be the same. Assuming they must all be distinct, you'll have a variation of a [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)

There are different algorithms to make a magic square depending on whether `n` is odd or even.

Once you have a magic square, each row and column will sum to some constant `N`

Divide all the numbers in the square by N

Comment: Here is a python module for generating magic squares https://pypi.python.org/pypi/magic_square